# Using react-chartjs-2 in Gatsby gives me a "cannot read properties of undefined" error in its components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, gatsby, react-chartjs

I'm trying to use react-chartjs-2 in a Gatsby project. I followed [this website](https://hackernoon.com/data-visualization-using-chartjs-and-gatsby) to write down a first test to see if it works. My code is:

```
import React from "react"
import { Chart, Arclement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js'
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2'

const data = {
    labels: ['Taxation', 'Materials', 'Profit', 'Expenses', 'Wages'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Tax bill',
        data: [25, 20, 8, 12, 34],
      },
    ],
};

const PieChart = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '750px' }}>
        <Pie data={data} />
      </div>
    );
};

const Artists = (props) => {
    let artistChart = getArtistChart(orderArtists(props.stats));
    return (
        <div id="statsCard">
            <PieChart />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at TypedRegistry.isForType (chart.esm.js:4756:1)
    at Registry._getRegistryForType (chart.esm.js:4899:1)
    at eval (chart.esm.js:4879:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Registry._each (chart.esm.js:4878:1)
    at Registry.add (chart.esm.js:4836:1)
    at Chart.value [as register] (chart.esm.js:6169:1)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/elements/artists.jsx:17:45)
    at ./src/pages/elements/artists.jsx (component---src-pages-index-js.js:62:1)
    at options.factory (commons.js:3711:31)
```

Is it caused by a wrong way to use chartjs inside Gatsby or can it be fixed the way it is?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) issues, so when the code is compiled in the Node server it fails.

I'd suggest importing the dependency directly into the client-side dynamically using [`React.Suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) or [`loadable` components](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components), leaving your code as:

```
import React from "react"
import { Chart, Arclement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js'
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
const { Pie } = loadable(() => import('react-chartjs-2'))

const data = {
    labels: ['Taxation', 'Materials', 'Profit', 'Expenses', 'Wages'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Tax bill',
        data: [25, 20, 8, 12, 34],
      },
    ],
};

const PieChart = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '750px' }}>
        <Pie data={data} />
      </div>
    );
};

const Artists = (props) => {
    let artistChart = getArtistChart(orderArtists(props.stats));
    return (
        <div id="statsCard">
            <PieChart />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or using `React.Suspense`:

```
const { Pie } = React.lazy(() => import("react-chartjs-2"));
import React from "react"

const data = {
  labels: ["Taxation", "Materials", "Profit", "Expenses", "Wages"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Tax bill",
      data: [25, 20, 8, 12, 34],
    },
  ],
};

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={"Loading"}>
      <div>
        <Pie data={data} />
      </div>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}
```

*Note: remove the `fallback` if not needed*

Another alternative solution is adding a `null` loader for the `react-chartjs-2` dependency by adding the following in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /react-chartjs-2/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

*Modified from: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/. In this docs you can also find more information about loadable components*

In the snippet above, test is a regular expression (that's why is between slashes, `/`) that it should match the folder name inside `node_modules` of the offending module.